# How to select only a few queries to show in GameQ

Tags: php

I am trying to get specific queries from a script called GameQ.

This is what I am getting:

[image: output]

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
// Include the main class file
require '../GameQ.php';

// Define your servers,
// see list.php for all supported games and identifiers.
$servers = array(
    array(
        'id' => 'CSGO1',
        'type' => 'csgo',
        'host' => '190.0.164.154:27015',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'CSGO2',
        'type' => 'csgo',
        'host' => '190.0.164.154:27016',
    )
);


// Call the class, and add your servers.
$gq = new GameQ();
$gq->addServers($servers);

// You can optionally specify some settings
$gq->setOption('timeout', 4); // Seconds

// You can optionally specify some output filters,
// these will be applied to the results obtained.
$gq->setFilter('stripcolor');

// Send requests, and parse the data
$results = $gq->requestData();


// Some functions to print the results
function print_results($results) {

    foreach ($results as $id => $data) {

        printf("<h2>%s</h2>\n", $id);
        print_table($data);
    }

}

function print_table($data) {

    $gqs = array('gq_online', 'gq_address', 'gq_port', 'gq_prot', 'gq_type');


    if (!$data['gq_online']) {
        printf("<p>The server did not respond within the specified time.</p>\n");
        return;
    }

    print("<table><thead><tr><td>Variable</td><td>Value</td></tr></thead><tbody>\n");

    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {

        if (is_array($val)) continue;

        $cls = empty($cls) ? ' class="uneven"' : '';

        if (substr($key, 0, 3) == 'gq_') {
            $kcls = (in_array($key, $gqs)) ? 'always' : 'normalise';
            $key = sprintf("<span class=\"key-%s\">%s</span>", $kcls, $key);
        }

        printf("<tr%s><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", $cls, $key, $val);
    }

    print("</tbody></table>\n");

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>GameQ - Example script</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                font-size: 9pt;
                font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 12pt;
            }
            h2 {
                margin-top:2em;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
            table {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                background-color: #DDD;
                border-spacing:1px 1px;
            }
            table thead {
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #CCC;
            }
            table tr.uneven td {
                background-color:#FFF;
            }
            table td {
                padding: 5px 8px;
            }
            table tbody {
                background-color: #F9F9F9;
            }
            .note {
                color: #333;
                font-style:italic;
            }
            .key-always {
                color:red;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            .key-normalise {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>GameQ - Example script</h1>
    <div class="note">
    Players are never displayed in this example. <br/>
    <span class="key-always">Bold, red</span> variables are always set by gameq.
    Additionally, the normal <span class="key-normalise">red</span> variables are always set when the normalise filter is enabled.<br/>
    gq_online will always contain a boolean indicating if the server responded to the request.<br/>
    <br/>
    Click <a href="list.php">here</a> for a list of supported games.
    </div>
<?php
    print_results($results);
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The files are available [here](https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ/releases/tag/v2.0.4)

I only want to show The hostname, map, max_players, num_players, gp_online, gp_adress, gp_port.

Comment: This is the exact example script that comes with GameQ. What have you tried to achieve what you want?

Comment: just a hint, you can create an array of acceptable variables and in your loop check if your `$key` in in that array then show it, else, not include it in the list. please do some research on it and then if you had problems with it come back to us.